# IList<KeyValuePair> vs IDictionary to serve as [DataMember] in WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, list, dictionary

I have a dictionary data structure that must be passed around using WCF. To do that I created a member property with get and set methods. I can basicly achieve the same functionality, with this property being either a:

```
IDictionary<keyType, valueType>
```

or a

```
IList<KeyValuePair<keyType, valueType>>
```

I can see no strong reason for choosing one over the other. One mild reaons I could think of is:

IDictionary - People reading the code will think that IDictionary makes more sense, since the data structure is a dictionary, but in terms of what is passed through WCF they are all the same.

Can anyone think of a reason to choose IList? If there is none I'll just go with IDictionary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Design your interfaces based on use, not on implementation.

If the consumer of a class needs to iterate through the entire set, use `IEnumerable`.  If they should be able to modify the result, and need index-based access, return `IList`.  If they want specific items, and there is a single useful key value, return `IDictionary`.

Write your internal code this way, too :)

Comment: The consumer is my own code, and the only putpose of the property is make the Data structure serializable by WCF. The only thing the getter setter does is enumerate the structure's members, so yout alternative of IEnumerable seems like the simplest thing that can work, which is always nice :-)

Comment: @David: "the only purpose of the property is make the Data structure serializable by WCF".  I can't claim to fully understand your scenario without seeing the code, but it sounds like you might have some mixed levels of abstraction in your design, which are causing decisions like this to be overly complicated.

Comment: Can you ellaborate on that comment?

Comment: @David: Unfortunately, without the code to look at, I can only speculate :)  The reason I said that, though, is that my mental picture of the code started becoming fuzzy.  What sort of class would a property like that belong in?  Properties exist because they make sense to their consumers, in the context of a class.  If you have a property that doesn't fit well in context of a class, then maybe it doesn't belong in that class, or your class is doing too many things, or you have the wrong set of abstractions, entirely.  What sort of class does that property live in, and what is the class's job?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your consumers. I would cater for the most likely use case and make their API as simple as possible. Edge cases can always iterate the dictionary via the Values collection.

Don't make them think about it. If the the term dictionary is what they'd think about as the result of the operation and then the type with name is a very useful thing to use.

Answer (score 0):

If the collection of keyValuePairs expects unique key, you can use dictionary.
If the same key can appear in more than one keyValuePair, use Ilist/ ienumerable.